# Android APK Digital Signature

Tags: android, apk, signing

The Android Development Guide mentions the following:
"Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority. Android apps often use self-signed certificates. The app developer holds the certificate's private key."

Does anyone know the repercussions of not digitally signing your application ?

Comment: Google Play doesn't accept non-signed applications

Comment: You cannot do anything if you don't sign your App - it simply won't install.

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot publish your APK to Google Play Store.
- If you have a published app on Google Play Store, all updates that you make to your application must be signed with the same keystore; otherwise you cannot update your application.